# Google app engine kills instance startup

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Since a few days my application is not started. After 1 minute of application startup it gets killed. This makes it unable to be ready for request processing.

Do you know how to extend this timeout ?

The logs of the server show a kill of the application after 61 seconds. Underneath I'm using Spring and there is a bean classpath exploration. I guess this is what is making the startup slow.

I'm working in reducing this time but it still shouldn't prevent my application to start.

Comment: Do the logs in the App Engine dashboard contain anything of interest?

Comment: Just random class failures being explored by the spring bean instantiator. At every kill different classes ar gotten which makes me think the kill is by a timeout and not an error.

Comment: no way to extend the timeout. what kind of app is this that it needs more than a minute to load? the problem is not GAE but you app, i suggest you to profile it and see where it takes that long. we are not in the 70ies any more so an app has no reason to take that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 60 second deadline for handling each request.

You might consider using a [warmup request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests) but you should really try to work on reducing your startup time.  It's often a few seconds for most apps.

I've seen some discussion on the App Engine mailing list on how to reduce startup times in Java, you might want to do some searches there.